# Subsumption of clauses, logic

Tags: logic

I've read something about clauses in mathematical logic and I don't understand the following.

I know that a disjunct clause $\kappa_1$ subsumes a clause $\kappa_2$, if $\kappa_2$ contains all literals $L$ that are appearing in $\kappa_1$. So for example the clause $\kappa_1=A\vee\neg B$ subsumes the clause $\kappa_2=A\vee \neg B \vee C$.

But why can I just omit every clause that gets subsumed by another clause when I have a set of clauses $K$?

Let's say my set of clauses is the following $K=\{\kappa_1, \kappa_2\}$ with $\kappa_1=A\vee B$ and $\kappa_2=A\vee B\vee C$. Let's say $A, B$ are both false and $C$ is true. Then $\kappa_1$ is false and $\kappa_2$ is true. But I am still allowed to remove $\kappa_2$ from $K$ because it gets subsumed by $\kappa_1$ but why am I allowed to do that? I obviously don't understand something fundamental but what?

Comment: Satisfiability: if k1 is sat, also k2 is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to remove clauses that are subsumed by other clauses from a set of clauses because subsumed clauses do not add any additional information or constraints to the set of clauses.

In your example, $κ_2$ can be safely removed without changing the meaning or implications of the set of clauses is because $(A\lor B)\land (A\lor B\lor C)\Leftrightarrow(A\lor B)$ holds in propositional logic.